# TDD for Cocos2d-X in android

Tags: android, eclipse, tdd, cocos2d-x, ccsprite

How do I write the TDD for "**is sprite added or not**" in the scene for cocos2d-x in eclipse. Here is my code

```
CCSprite *sprite  =null;

//adding sprite code
sprite = new CCSprite();
sprite->initWithSpriteFrameName(“abc.png");
this->addChild(sprite);
```

Any blog or help in right direction will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you [don't test the platform](http://b-speaking.blogspot.ca/2009/08/integration-tests-are-scam.html) (or framework) you're using. You trust that it works. You do need to test that your code interacts with it correctly instead.

This usually means hiding external APIs behind an interface, and then mocking that interface. This [video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam) explains how to approach that.